# android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:

Tags: android, android-activity, android-manifest

I am getting this exception while I am trying to call an activity from another one.  The complete exception is

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:Unable to find explicit activity class {com.x.y/com.x.y.class};

I am doing an `intent.setClass("com.x.y","com.x.y.className")` where `className` is the name of my activity class and `com.x.y` is the package it resides in.

My AndroidManifest.xml has the following content:

```
<activity android:name="com.x.y.className" android:label="@string/app_name">
```

Am I missing anything?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Maybe you need to check that you added the new activity to the manifest.xml file

Example:

```
<activity
      android:name=".className" 
      android:label="@string/app_name" > 
</activity>
```

Comment: I already have the following entry :

<activity android:name="com.x.y.className" android:label="@string/app_name"> </activity>

Still no luck :(

Comment: @paypalcomp It looks like you added the full package name to the activity name. Try removing that so your entry looks like: <activity android:name=".className" android:label="@string/app_name"> </activity>

Comment: @Corey I found that using the full package name (referring to the library) used in the manifest file of the main application works for me.

Comment: @user94154 Me too. For some reason, the `.ActivityClassName` notation works in the standlone run, but not when invoked from a different application via Intent. +1 for confirming that I am not hallucinating.

Comment: For some reason i have similar problem... Nothing really works i have tried to change activity names with full package names. Tried to call intent in many different ways. Even tried to put it in try catch, as mentioned below. I have no idea what is going on

Answer (score 16):

If other people are encountering something similar and arrive at this post, an issue I had may save you some time. May not be related to the OP's problem but def related to the ActivityNotFound exception.

I was trying to load an activity by using:

```
Intent intent = new Intent( this, class );
```

However I continuously kept getting the `ActivityNotFoundException` even though I had checked and rechecked the code multiple times.

This exception I was getting wasn't actually being caused by the intent but some code I was running inside the loaded activity throwing a `RuntimeException`. (my issue was caused by `Typeface.createFromAsset()`)

It is possible you are running into a similar RuntimeException in your activity.

To see if this is the case, put your intent code in try catch blocks. Like so:

```
try {
    /* your code */
    ...
} catch ( ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Run your app again, and check your LogCat, if it's the same issue, you'll get a RuntimeException with a "Caused By:" entry pointing to your actual issue.

I spent a good hour trying to figure this out. Hopefully this may save someone some time.

Comment: Thank you! Commenting out the onCreate activity in the target activity made the problem go away. Clearly, one needs to take the recommendation to double-check the manifest with a grain of salt.

Answer (score 14):

The activity you are calling should appear not only in the Manifest for its own package, but in the Manifest for the CALLING package, too.

Comment: Do you mean that if I import a project to my workspace as a library project, I should also copy the `<activity>` element from the manifest in the library project to the manifest of my project?

Answer (score 8):

Delete your activity from the manifest and then add it again. This type do not write type the XML directly. Instead, go to `Application > Application nodes > add`, choose the Activity, and then browse for the file source.

This worked for me.

Comment: weird bug this fixed it for me ty:)

Answer (score 3):

intent.setClass takes parameters as "Package Context" and "Class".
an example would be:

```
intent.setClass(CurrentActivity.this, TargetActivity.class);
```

also you need to check if the activity is registered in manifest file.

Answer (score 2):

Added a new activity and defined it in manifest.xml, but I was still getting "Unable to find explicit activity class" error. I am using Eclipse. Solution for my problem was "cleaning" the project. From the main menu in Eclipse: Project|Clean.... Then you select your project and clean it.

Answer (score 1):

Hey, you need to use another form of Intent constructor. This will surely solve your issue within a second:

Example:

```
Intent inte=new Intent(getBaseContext(),"your class name with .class extension ");

startActivity(inte);
```

This works perfectly and I checked this code, its working properly.

Answer (score 1):

I had an ActivityNotFoundException when I implemented the Activity inside another class (as an inner class):

```
//... inside the utility class Pref
public static class Activity extends PreferenceActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        addPreferencesFromResource(R.xml.prefs);
    }
}
//...
```

Declared as the following inside the manifest:

```
<activity android:name=".Pref.Activity"
...
```

After declaring this as a normal class (public class PrefActicity) and changing manifest accordingly, it worked as usual.

Answer (score 1):

I was using `getActivityContext()` (instead of `Activity.this`) for the menu code to save some work, and copy-and-paste it to each activity without editing each time.

I replaced them with `Activity.this`, and the issue is gone.

I have a feeling a smarter Android guy could work-around not having to do that. Would like to hear what it would be.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the documentation  [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#setClass(android.content.Context,%20java.lang.Class%3C?%3E))  what you want is:

```
intent.setClassName("com.x.y", "className");
```

Comment: Thank u for the quick answer :) .. But I am using the following method 
"setClassName(String packageName, String className)" of the Intent class.. And my manifest file contains the following entry :

<activity android:name="com.x.y.className" android:label="@string/app_name">
      
  </activity>

Should I add any intent filters ? I am creating my Intent with the following code :

 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
 intent.setClassName("com.x.y", className.class.getName());
 activity.startActivity(intent);

Comment: I believe you will need to add 
<intent-filter>
  <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
</intent-filter>
Between your activity tags in the manifest file.

Comment: Nope.. Still no luck.. Get this error :
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.x.y/com.x.y.className}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

Added the following in my Manifest file :

<activity android:name="com.x.y.className" android:label="@string/app_name">
  <intent-filter> <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" /> </intent-filter>      
  </activity>

:(

Comment: Anyways.. did 
 Intent intent = new Intent(activity,CartActivity.class);
 activity.startActivity(intent);

and it worked like a charm :)

Thank you soo much

Answer (score 0):

Restart the Eclipse and check your Manifestfile again. If you find missing the respective Activity, then add it and try again. It solved my similar issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try using the following:

```
intent.setClassName("com.x.y", "com.x.y.className");
```

This works for me

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Mina's answer.
When you declare activity as inner static class then you should write your activity into manifest like ...

```
         <activity android:name=".app.FragmentLayoutSupport$DetailsActivity" />
```

here .app comes from your package name , it can be .helpers.afdfa$afda

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this error was to add a package name in front of the name in manifest.

I had the following activities:

- id.scanner.main.A1
- id.scanner.main.gallery.A2

My manifest contained the following:

```
<activity android:name=".A1" ....></activity>
<activity android:name=".A2" ....></activity>
```

This solved the problem:

```
<activity android:name=".A1" ....></activity>
<activity android:name="gallery.A2" ....></activity>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I got this problem too. I refreshed the project. And then, everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

when i have same issue. if you are using library class files and writing it into android manifest files write it like  and then remove the library projects manifest files this portion>>   
        
 then it will work absolutely..

Answer (score 0):

This exception also occurs if you include a library in your app and if the library is calling an activity defined in the library project. In this case we need to merge library's manifest with calling app's manifest.

With ADT version 20, we can do this by adding the below statement in project.properties of calling app.

**manifestmerger.enabled=true**

Answer (score 0):

Check out the content of the Android Manifest File in the bin folder of the project. When your app is compiled and packaged the Manifest File is copied to the bin folder. In my case the Manifest in the bin folder did not agree with the original Manifest. This is probably a mistake of Eclipse. I manually copied the Manifest to the bin folder and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

you can add this code in `manifiest.xml` file

```
action android:name="com.kaushalam.activity101activity.SecondActivity"
category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the same case too. After reading thepearson's answer, I revised my Activity and found out that I wrote

```
public void onCreate(Bundle s)
```

But in fact it should be

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle s)
```

And it works now!

Answer (score 0):

This works if you have an Activity object (which you need to launch):

```
intent.setClassName(CallingActivity.this, activityToLaunch.getComponentName().getClassName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Activity you're calling sholdn't contain "sheme" and contain intent-filter:

```
<activity android:name=".SecondActivity">
        <intent-filter>
               <action android:name="com.example.sj.myapplication.SecondActivity"/>
               <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
        </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

so in calling code:

```
Intent intent=new Intent("com.example.sj.myapplication.SecondActivity");
startActivity(intent);
```

Answer (score 0):

I also ran into ActivityNotFoundException by passing the wrong view into setContentView(), each activity's class file must correspond with the layout xml file this way.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.wrongView);
}
```

as opposed to

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.correctView);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I had the same issue. I tried everything but the error, which I sorted out later, was that there was a space left between double quotes and my class name. It has to be:
`intent.setClassName("com.x.y","com.x.y.className")`

not

```
intent.setClassName("com.x.y","  com.x.y.className")
```