# (Android) Cannot call one activity from another in the same package

Tags: android, android-activity

I spent a very long time trying to locate the error but I can't seem to find an answer that works online. The situation is that LogCat produces this error every time I click on an option in the list: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class.

Manifest file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest package="com.capture.ProcessCapture"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" /><uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_TASKS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<application android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher" android:label="@string/app_name">
        <activity android:label="@string/app_name" android:name=".ProcessCaptureActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name=".FileData" android:label="@string/app_name">
        </activity>
        <service android:name=".BackgroundCapture" android:enabled="true" android:process=":Background" android:permission="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" android:label="@string/app_name"></service>
        <receiver android:name=".BootReceiver" android:label="@string/app_name" android:enabled="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

ProcessCaptureActivity.java (Main class):

```
package com.capture.ProcessCapture;
... (all the imports)

public class ProcessCaptureActivity extends ListActivity {
    private File dir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/ProcessCapture/data");
    private String accessedFile;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        onResume();
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_item, capturedFiles()));
        ListView lv = getListView();
        lv.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
              // Get file name:
                accessedFile = ((TextView) view).getText().toString();
                Intent newIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), FileData.class);
                newIntent.putExtra("filename", accessedFile);
                startActivity(newIntent);
            }
          });
    }

    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        //Timeout for 30min (Using AlarmManager)
        Intent myIntent = new Intent(this, BackgroundCapture.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
        alarmManager.cancel(pendingIntent);
        alarmManager.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.ELAPSED_REALTIME_WAKEUP, 0, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_HALF_HOUR, pendingIntent);
    }

    private String[] capturedFiles() {
        return dir.list();
    }

}
```

FileData.java

```
package com.capture.ProcessCapture;

... (all the imports)

public class FileData extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String filename = bundle.getString("filename");
        File file = new File(sdcard+"/ProcessCapture/data", filename);

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.file_data);
        tv.setText(text);

        setContentView(R.layout.file_data);
    }

}
```

Full LogCat: (Which only shows error when a list item is clicked)

```
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.capture.ProcessCapture/com.capture.ProcessCapture.FileData}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1379)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:2827)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:2933)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.capture.ProcessCapture.ProcessCaptureActivity$1.onItemClick(ProcessCaptureActivity.java:37)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:284)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.ListView.performItemClick(ListView.java:3513)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:1812)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
11-05 10:45:28.743: E/AndroidRuntime(907):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Thanks in advance! Sorry for the long question =)

Comment: "com.capture.ProcessCapture" package names should all be lower case, your code looks ok to me apart from that

Comment: try changing to complete names in AndroidManifest file i.e. "com.capture.ProcessCapture.FileData"

Comment: Hi, thanks so much for your quick response. However, that didn't solve the problem =( Thanks so much for trying though!

Comment: Hi guys, please put the problem on pause. I think it's because I'm using Windows =/ after i changed to my ubuntu, it started giving me another error instead. When I solve it, i'll mark it as solved (just in case this thing pops up again). Thanks so much!!! (especially those who read my long and boring code and answered to it - aaamos & Optimus)

Comment: Sorry, apparently I can't create my own answers... The problem was 'solved' when I changed to ubuntu instead of windows =/ The root problem was in FileData.java, where the setContentView(R.layout.file_data) had to be called before setting text to it's TextView (tv).

Comment: hmmm... i know, you'll have to earn some rep to do that, its irritating

Comment: Hopefully voting up your question will help with that rep - it was well asked and thorough, don't apologise for the question being long ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Copy from my comment above) The problem was 'solved' when I used ubuntu instead of windows =/ The root problem was in FileData.java, where the setContentView(R.layout.file_data) had to be called before setting text to it's TextView (tv).

The new code for FileData.java is:

```
package com.capture.ProcessCapture;

... (all the imports)

public class FileData extends Activity {

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        File sdcard = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

        Bundle bundle = this.getIntent().getExtras();
        String filename = bundle.getString("filename");
        File file = new File(sdcard+"/ProcessCapture/data", filename);

        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();

        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            String line;

            while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line);
                text.append('\n');
            }
        } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        setContentView(R.layout.file_data);

        TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.file_data);
        tv.setText(text);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433778/android-content-activitynotfoundexception) and the first answer, which suggests putting a try/catch block around the code that tries to start the activity, as sometimes it's not actually that the activity is indeed undeclared but another underlying problem.

If that doesn't work, you can always try cleaning and rebuilding the project, then getting Eclipse to resync (right-click on project, "Android Tools" -> "Fix Project Properties").

Comment: Thank you for replying. However, the "Fix Project Properties" method didn't do anything visible, and the stack trace pointed to the `startActivity(newIntent);` part of the code. However, i still can't find a solution...



`11-05 12:17:16.092: W/System.err(1251): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.capture.ProcessCapture/com.capture.ProcessCapture.FileData}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Comment: Glad to hear you've gotten rid of the problem. :-) Sometimes Eclipse gets its knickers in a twist, which is why I recommended trying the clean/build/sync approach.