# I thought there's only one manifest file in an Android Project

Tags: android

What's it means by that comment of "The activity you are calling should appear not only in the Manifest for its own package, but in the Manifest for the CALLING package, too."  I only have one package.

[android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433778/android-content-activitynotfoundexception)

Answer (score 3):

I think this is applicable for library projects . when your application is imported by other application and that application use your activity , both application's manifest need activity entry .