# Random ActivityNotFoundException when launching Intent

Tags: android, exception

I have an app, that had run hundreds of times fine, but very rarely I get an exception while trying to launch activity:

```
Intent tIntent = new Intent();
tIntent.setClass(App.ctx, MyClassActivity.class);
startActivity(tIntent);
```

In manifest I have declared:

```
activity android:name="MyClassActivity" android:launchMode="singleTask"
```

Exception:

```
 01-01 10:41:33.723: E/AndroidRuntime(3867): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: 
 Unable to find explicit activity class {my.package/my.package.MyClassActivity}; 
 have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
```

Any hints what could be causing this? Exception is really random and rare. Application is launched on emulator.

I've read [android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433778/android-content-activitynotfoundexception) question but there a problem is systematic, not random like here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running the program in an emulator, then I am going to assume that you are often debugging changes. If this is not the case, please give clarification, however, I will base my answer on this assumption for now...

Whenever an app is run in a development or debuggable environment, either on the emulator or a device, there is a lot that happens. As a result, it can skew load-times, installations, uninstallations, etc. Most often, this happens after a quick change on an already started device (that is a device plugged in via USB, or an emulator that you keep open as you develop).

To start this on the device, it does the following:
 1. Rebuilds the Application (if there were any changes)
 2. Checks if the Application matches the one on the device.
 3. Uninstalls/Reinstalls the Application
 4. Runs the Application.

During this process, if things happen too quickly, it can misread your manifest file and "corrupt" (not really) your build. If it only happens intermittently, then it is just the emulator fizzling for a minute. If the problem happens and then continues until you do something specific, it is the development environment getting lost. For the first issue, there's really nothing you can do but not click so quickly sometimes... For the second, just "clean" the project (in Eclipse this is done by clicking Project -> Clean). This will get rid of the cached information and build it from scratch again. It makes your application behave like it was all shiny and new. Something else that I find helps sometimes is uninstalling the app manually from the device, as well. I only do this with complicated apps that use multiple libraries or when the ContentResolver gets hung up due to a Content error.

Hope this helps,
FuzzicalLogic

Comment: Thanks for comprehensive answer. I also suspect that it is a glitch of an emulator but as far as I remember when exception happened it was in quite clean state (e.g. no additional build being uploaded into emulator while I was clicking on previous one). Also I regularly uninstall app using adb commandline as I need to clear preferences and this is quickest way of doing this for me.

Comment: I don't think it is really a glitch in emulator, but in adb itself. I develop in Eclipse and this happens to me on devices and emulation. When it happens, I used to reset adb and it would fix it, but the I found that the above was faster and more reliable, as adb sometimes would not restart.

Answer (score 0):

Please add both activity in manifest file like this

```
                   <activity android:name=".MyClassActivity"
              android:label="@string/app_name"
              android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
              android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.pkg.MyClassActivity"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: What is the reason of adding this to manifest? I'm curious, as app runs just fine on hundreds of devices without those additional filters. You can try here: [TM.Lazor on Android Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=info.tmouse.tlazor), sorry for self-promotion, but maybe it'll help.