# Apllictication stops working

Tags: android, android-studio

Logcat Shows

```
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: Process: com.example.rahul.myapplication, PID: 15064
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime: android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.rahul.myapplication/com.example.rahul.myapplication.StudentDetail}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1794)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1512)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3917)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3877)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4200)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4168)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.example.rahul.myapplication.MainActivity.onClick(MainActivity.java:52)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5198)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21147)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
10-16 13:51:51.310 15064-15064/com.example.rahul.myapplication E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

My android manifest file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.rahul.myapplication" >

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please help me the program wont work after i click add button and in intent
call student details class...................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................

Comment: ActivityNotFoundException not found excption means you haven't declared your activity in the manifest file

Comment: You didn't declare the `StudentDetail` Activity in your manifest.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433778/android-content-activitynotfoundexception)

Comment: You should have spent a bit more time reading your logcat:  `[...] Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.rahul.myapplication/com.example.rahul.myapplication.StudentDetail}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?`

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your manifest:

```
<activity
   android:name=".StudentDetail"
   android:label="@string/student_label"
   android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add every Activity of your Applicationin your manifest file. Inorder to add StudentDetail Activity, add this code in your manifest:

```
 <activity
        android:name=".StudentDetail"
        android:label="yourAppLabel"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />
```

Note that you can keep your own label and theme for your activity. Here the theme used is AppTheme.NoActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add StudentDetail activity to your manifest file
Add

```
<activity android:name=".StudentDetaill" ></activity>
```

Answer (score -1):

Write below code in manifest

```
 <activity
        android:name=".StudentDetail"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" >

    </activity>
```