# can't open the page, android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, oncreate

I'm programming an individual app. I've got an strange problem. Yesterday the app was ok and today when i want to go to another  page the app stoped. It is only one page which stoped.

this is a piece of my code from this page:

```
@Override
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lebensmittel_start_seite);

    infoText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.leb_info_text);
    infoText.setText("Die Kohlenhydratmenge bei abgepackten Lebensmitteln und " +
            "Fertigprodukten finden Sie bei den Nährwertangaben. Die KE können " +
            "Sie berechnen, indem Sie die Kohlenhydratmenge pro 100 g durch 10 teilen." +
            "Beispiel: 100 g Schokolade = 48 g Kohlenhydrate 48 g / 10 = 4,8 KE");

    spinner1=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    spinner2=(Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner_leb);
    ArrayAdapter adapter1= createFromResource(this, R.array.menue_array, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    ArrayAdapter adapter2= createFromResource(this, R.array.Lebensmittel_Liste, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    spinner1.setAdapter(adapter1);
    spinner2.setAdapter(adapter2);
    spinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    spinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

this is my logcat:

```
09-20 09:39:02.237 2592-2592/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe, PID: 2592
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe.LebensmittelSeiten.Lebensmittel_Start_Seite}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
   at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1932)
   at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1615)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4472)
   at android.support.v4.app.BaseFragmentActivityJB.startActivityForResult(BaseFragmentActivityJB.java:54)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:75)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:4430)
   at android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity.startActivityForResult(FragmentActivity.java:708)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4791)
   at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4759)
   at com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe.Start.onItemSelected(Start.java:60)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.fireOnSelected(AdapterView.java:944)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.dispatchOnItemSelected(AdapterView.java:933)
   at android.widget.AdapterView.-wrap1(Unknown Source:0)
   at android.widget.AdapterView$SelectionNotifier.run(AdapterView.java:898)
   at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
   at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
   at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
   at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6541)
   at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
   at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:240)
   at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:767)
```

Comment: Do you have any error log/stack trace?

Comment: I added my logcat

Comment: Just in case I found my problem and fix it

Comment: Logs are very helpful. So, do check error logs first, if the error log is clear enough to fix the error else post your question along with stack trace. We're here to help you to get rid from errors. Happy coding.

Comment: yeah I will look at first at my logcat next time =)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433778/android-content-activitynotfoundexception)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe/com.example.mac.diabetikerhilfe.LebensmittelSeiten.Lebensmittel_Start_Seite}; 
AndroidManifest.xml?**

Declared Your Activity on AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
   <activity android:name=".ActivityName"/>

   </applications>
```

Comment: yes i found out what was my problem and fixed it
Thank you