# Application crash starting another activity with error ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: java, android

I'm new in the android world.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    public Button printButton, contactButton, whereButton, commButton;
    public ImageButton newsButton;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        printButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.stampa);
        contactButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.contattaci);
        whereButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.dovesiamo);
        commButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.comunicazioni);
        newsButton = (ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.news);

        printButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                Intent intent = new Intent(context, PrintActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

`PrintActivity.class` exists and he's linked to a layout xml file that exist.

But when I run my application on my mobile and tap to Print Button it crashes. What's wrong? Thank you.

Here's the error that is showing.

> android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit
>   activity class
>   {it.cartoleriadipiu.dipiapp/it.cartoleriadipiu.dipiapp.PrintActivity};

Comment: what is the logcat showing on crashing.. have you mention your second activity in manifest

Comment: @FranCode Post your stacktrace

Comment: It seems that my application doesn't find the activity that I want switch for. But it exist in my project. How can it happen?

Comment: Check your manifest to see of `PrintActivity` is listed. And instead of `getApplicationContext()` as the context use `MainActivity.this`

Comment: post your manifest

Comment: Yes guys I forgot to write the activity inside the manifest. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433778/android-content-activitynotfoundexception)

Comment: FranCode :: Just an additional tip--There is no need to declare your `Button` or `ImageButton` objects as public. I suggest that you review java object declaration in regard to scope. (public, private, protected as well as static, and final).

Answer (score 0):

Add your `PrintActivity` in your `AndroidManifest.xml` file defining it as an activity like the following.

```
<activity
    android:name="it.cartoleriadipiu.dipiapp.PrintActivity"
    android:label="Print Activity" />
```