# ndroid.content.ActivityNotFoundException:

Tags: android, android-app-bundle, android-dynamic-shortcuts

android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.myapp.videomodule/com.myapp.videomodule.VideoCallActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?

My app package is com.myapp.doctors
module package is com.myapp.videomodule

```
if(splitInstallManager.getInstalledModules().contains("videomodule")){
Intent intent = new Intent(); 
intent.setClassName("com.myapp.videomodule", "com.myapp.videomodule.VideoCallActivity");
startActivity(intent); 
}
```

I have declared it in the manifest the thing is I am trying dymanic module delivery, so that videoactivity is in other module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [android.content.ActivityNotFoundException:](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3433778/android-content-activitynotfoundexception)

Comment: savvisingh's question is related to dynamic features, in his case he will not have reference to the activity they want to start. Therefore not related to the issue you linked Abhiskek. 

They need to start the activity by name, however even so they are getting that error. I am actually facing the same issue even after: `if(splitInstallManager.getInstalledModules().contains("mymodule"))` succeeds. :( – Matt Carron 52 secs ago    Edit   Delete

Comment: I faced this issue and I believe ran into the same mistake. Nico's answer was correct for me and likely for this question too.

I had the application package name and the activity's package name the same in my `setClassName` which was the issue.

In my case my dynamic module had a different package name to the app module so to fix this I had something like this:

`intent.setClassName("com.myapp.appmodule", "com.myapp.videomodule.VideoCallActivity");`

Answer (score 2):

It seems that dynamic feature modules are declared in base app package. (as you can verify using *Merged Manifest* feature on your module `Manifest.xml`

I suggest the following modification:

```
if(splitInstallManager.getInstalledModules().contains("videomodule")){
    Intent intent = new Intent(); 
    intent.setClassName(getPackageName(), "com.myapp.videomodule.VideoCallActivity");
    startActivity(intent); 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Go to `manifests` > `AndroidManifest.xml` > check if `com.myapp.videomodule.VideoCallActivity` is declared there, if not, put it like:

```
<manifest>

.... 

<application
        ...>

        ...

        <activity
            android:name="com.myapp.videomodule.VideoCallActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_videocallactivity" your activity title 
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar" />

        ...
</application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: I have declared it in the manifest the thing is I am trying dymanic module delivery, so that videoactivity is in other module

Answer (score -1):

Try starting the intent like this:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, VideoCallActivity.class);
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: This is the classic ways to start an activity, but the author is in dynamics feature context.